# Fix mix UEFI (Windows 10) with Legacy (Ubuntu) boot issues

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi

I'm running a dual-boot system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04) but after recently resolving an issue with Legacy vs UEFI boot modes, Windows 10 no longer shows up as a boot option.

Some backstory: I was following a guide (sorry, I can't find the link) that suggested install Windows first, then Ubuntu since Ubuntu is more flexible with boot options and loaders than Windows.

I remember Windows installing using UEFI per its recommendation. Things went smoothly. Once in Windows I updated the drivers and firmware for my system. Following that I installed Ubuntu and again, things went smoothly. I was able to dual boot.

However, a week or so ago I somehow managed to enable Secure Boot, which messed up the boot loader. After reading and research I ended up using Boot-Repair to get Ubuntu up and running. I also had to enable Legacy boot mode, but in the end I was able to get back into Ubuntu. Unfortunately, Windows 10 no longer appeared on the boot menu.

When I use programs like fdisk, gparted, or parted the Windows partition doesn't even show up and after more reading I'm wondering if somehow the two operating systems are using different boot methods (i.e., Ubuntu is using Legacy and Windows is on UEFI).

If I change the boot options to UEFI, rather than booting Windows, I get Dell's recovery app. Switching back to Legacy allows Ubuntu to load via Grub.

**Is there a way to repair the bootloader such that both Ubuntu and Windows are boot options without having to wipe and reinstall everything?**

Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: You just about had to have reinstalled grub's BIOS version from Boot-Repair, replacing the UEFI version of grub. If you have an UEFI system, you need to always boot in UEFI mode, both system and flash drives. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode, if booting in UEFI mode to uninstall grub-pc (BIOS) and install grub-efi-amd64 (UEFI).

Comment: If I do this, and boot into Linux using UEFI, will I be able to then see my Windows partitions?

Also, I should have added this earlier, the option to "Repair Windows boot files" in Boot Repair is dimmed and unselectable. I see /dev/sda2 but it is unrecognized and the same size as the Ubuntu partition, despite it being the Windows install with only 20GB.

Comment: Then you left Windows hibernated or its fast startup on. That must be off. Linux will not normally mount a NTFS partition that is hibernated or if it needs chkdsk to prevent damage by user writing into it and corrupting it.

Comment: How would I check if it's in fast mode from Linux, and turn it off? I'm afraid of corrupting my installs, so I'm hoping that getting them both on UEFI (or alternatively both on legacy) is feasible.

Comment: From Linux you cannot check if Windows fast start up or hibernation is on, other than LInux NTFS driver will give errors in trying to mount it.

Comment: See [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html) for instructions on disabling Fast Startup and Hibernation, respectively. See [this page of mine](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for information on why mixing BIOS-mode and EFI-mode OSes can be such a problem.

Comment: @RodSmith Always great info, thanks. I think I'm going to just reformat and start from scratch. I'm tweaking this and that trying to fix it and I've lost track of all the things I've tweaked. Probably not good. I'll just do it all again in the coming weeks. For now, Ubuntu works which is my main OS anyway so I can deal for the time being.

When I reformat and reinstall, I'll do Windows first in UEFI, then Ubuntu in UEFI, and I should be golden. Is that right?

Comment: In most cases, yes, EFI mode is better than BIOS mode on modern computers; and it's usually best to install Windows first. There are exceptions, though -- mostly on computers that are more than a couple of years old and that therefore have early (and buggy) EFI implementations. Unfortunately, some manufacturers seem to be dragging their feet about fixing their EFIs' problems, so some issues persist today. Updating your firmware to the latest version before you re-install may be a worthwhile precaution.